# add keys together in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary

Hei guys! I need help in a python program. I wanna make a method which returns the sum of the keys as a dictionary. But I get a error `"object is not iterable".`

```
def totaltAntallSalg (dic) :
   s = sum (dic.keys)
   return s

call_function = totaltAntallSalg({"Ahmed":2,"Nada":1, "hala":3 })
```

How can I solve  this problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you add strings ? It might be values that you want to add.

To add values you may use following code:-

```
def totaltAntallSalg(dic):
   D={}
   D['sum']=sum(dic.values())
   return D
```